# Is there a way to pause the Media Object when a Suggestion Chip has been clicked - while the Media Object is playing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I have an audio clip that pays when a specific intent has been triggered. A set of suggestion chips are displayed along with it. Now when I test it out in the simulator or my phone the MediaObject works fine but if I continue to the next intent using a suggestion chip the MediaObject doesn't pause automatically. Which in-turn overlaps with the next intents SSML.
I'm unable to get a sample code or any reference on how to pause MediaObject audio.

I've tried adding a blank audio clip in an SSML before the next intent starts, so to auto cancel the MediaObject, which failed.

I expect that when the user clicks on a Suggestion Chip while a MediaObject is playing - the Audio clip must pause automatically. And it should not overlap with the next intents SSML.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to reproduce the issue and have filed an internal bug.

There isn't an API to pause the music.

Comment: Thank you! As we have a lot of such applications out there and users would think its the applications that are not working right. If there is a better way to deal with it let me know.